# Hacer count en varios campos mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Buenas, tengo una db en mysql, quisiera realizar el conteo de un valor determinado en muchos campos en una misma tabla (no en un solo campo), por ejemplo en este caso tengo la tabla
A= Aceptable
S= Sobresaliente
E = Excelente
Tabla: notas

[image]

Como pueden ver no es un simple count, ya que hay varios campos de notas para diferentes estudiantes, quiero por ejemplo contar las A, las S y las E en los diferentes campos de todos los estudiantes, gracias y espero me haya sabido explicar.

Comment: Aunque les parezca un dato inutil, quiero saber cuantas notas son sobresaliente "S" en toda la base de datos, es decir, teniendo en cuenta todos los estudiantes y todas las notas, no un solo estudiante, como sería? gracias nuevamente

Comment: solo las S?? o el resto tambien?

Comment: Como quieras, el resto podría hacerlo si tengo tan solo un ejemplo, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Esta consulta te cuenta cada nota, y te da un nombre de fila para cada una. No está mal ¿no?

```
SELECT nota, COUNT(*) total 
    FROM (
            SELECT nota1 as nota FROM estudiantes_20171010
            UNION ALL
            SELECT nota2 as nota FROM estudiantes_20171010
            UNION ALL
            SELECT nota3 as nota FROM estudiantes_20171010
            UNION ALL
            SELECT nota4 as nota FROM estudiantes_20171010
            UNION ALL
            SELECT nota5 as nota FROM estudiantes_20171010

    ) tbl_tmp
GROUP BY nota;
```

Aunque yo mejoraría el diseño de la base de datos, así nos evitas dolores de cabeza ... :)  Una simple tabla que guarde `id_estudiante`,  `id_asignatura` y `nota` daría un respiro interesante a la tabla `estudiantes`, te permitiría contar lo que quieras, aunque fueran miles de tipos de notas, etc...

Espero te sea útil.

### Código

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/GDJD12077)**</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS estudiantes_20171010 
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    nombre VARCHAR(20), nota1 CHAR(1), nota2 CHAR(1),nota3 CHAR(1),nota4 CHAR(1),nota5 CHAR(1)
)ENGINE=INNODB;


INSERT INTO estudiantes_20171010 (nombre,nota1,nota2,nota3,nota4,nota5)
    VALUES 
    ('Estudiante1','E','S','S','A','S'),
    ('Estudiante2','A','S','A','E','S'),
    ('Estudiante3','S','E','S','S','S')
;

-- Datos de prueba 

SELECT *
FROM estudiantes_20171010
;

-- Contando notas

SELECT nota, COUNT(*) total 
    FROM (
            SELECT nota1 as nota FROM estudiantes_20171010
            UNION ALL
            SELECT nota2 as nota FROM estudiantes_20171010
            UNION ALL
            SELECT nota3 as nota FROM estudiantes_20171010
            UNION ALL
            SELECT nota4 as nota FROM estudiantes_20171010
            UNION ALL
            SELECT nota5 as nota FROM estudiantes_20171010

    ) tbl_tmp
GROUP BY nota;
```

--Datos de prueba

```
id  nombre         nota1    nota2   nota3   nota4   nota5
1   Estudiante1    E        S       S       A       S
2   Estudiante2    A        S       A       E       S
3   Estudiante3    S        E       S       S       S
```

--Conteo

```
nota    total
A       3
E       3
S       9
```

Comment: Uf! Muy buena esa! :D

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, como todas los caracteres a contar ocupan una posicion, se puede hacer un pequeño truco para contar los caracteres.

Separemos el query en dos..

Primero tenemos que obtener una sola cadena por Estudiante:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(nota_1,nota_2,...) as concatenado
FROM 
    TABLA
```

y luego, contamos por cada fila la cantidad de cada aparicion, esto solo vale porque es una letra! si no la funcion seria un poco mas complicada.

```
SELECT
    LENGTH(concatenado) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( concatenado, "A", "") ) as NOTAS_A,
    LENGTH(concatenado) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( concatenado, "E", "") ) as NOTAS_E,
    LENGTH(concatenado) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( concatenado, "S", "") ) as NOTAS_S
FROM 
   TABLA_ANTERIOR
```

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar variables, por ejemplo:

```
// Se cuentan todas las S de la columna nota1 y se mete en variable
select count(*) from asignatura where Nota1='S' into @valor1;

// Se cuentan todas las S de la columna nota2 y se mete en variable
select count(*) from asignatura where Nota2='S' into @valor2;

// Hay que repetir las sentencias anteriores por cada columna de cada tabla.

// Se suman todas las variables y te da el número total de S por tabla.
select @valor1 + @valor2;
```

Probablemente se pueda optimizar esta consulta cambiando el Where, diciendo que cuente cualquiera de las S que encuentre, pero ahora mismo es lo primero que se me viene.